# Add HTML inbetween, {freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is it possible to output the previously selected values using 'mp_data' and freeform multipage with some HTML separating the values?

At the moment I have a field with dates in, a user selects some dates, and on the second page either displays the values they selected OR if no values were selected show another 'textarea' field asking why they haven’t selected any dates.

At the moment, it just outputs all the values raw.

```
Monday 14th September Tuesday 15th September Wednesday 16th September Thursday 17th September Friday 18th September
```

Is it possible to add a comma or HTML element to separate them.

```
Desired Result:
Monday<br/>
Tuesday<br/>
Wednesday<br/>

Current Code:
{if freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}{freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}<br/>{/if}

Actual Result: 
MondayTuesdayWednesday
```

Comment: Please add your template code to your question. I've done what you're asking a million times, but I have to see your template to advise.

Comment: added to the bottom of the question, thanks.

Comment: Weeeeird.... Not at my office for another 40 minutes, but I rock freeform, so I'll do some tests and get back to you.

Comment: I'm currently encountering the exact same issue. Did you find a solution to this @Third_Hyperion?

Answer (score 0):

Hrmmm... weird one (I think).

Try expanding and adding carriage returns to your code:

```
{if freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}

    {freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}

    <br/>

    TESTING !!!

    <span> SPANNING! </span>

    <!-- COMMENTING! -->

    <br/>

{/if}
```

What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using manually-coded form fields (i.e. not using `{freeform:field:FIELD_NAME}`), and submitting an *array* of data in a field (i.e. your fields would have `name="my_field[]"` instead of `name="my_field"`), you might need to manually break down the data using PHP or a plugin that separates a string of data into iterable pieces of data. For example, this would output your data, broken down to an array, as a PHP variable dump (turn on PHP for your template!):

```
<?php $arr = explode("\n", '{freeform:mp_data:FIELD_NAME}'); ?>
<?php var_dump($arr); ?>
```

`var_dump()` isn't very useful outside of development/troubleshooting however: you would need to loop through your array data for better customization, like this for example:

```
<?php foreach($arr as $item) :?>
      <?php echo $item; ?><br />
<?php endforeach ?>
```